# Is there a way to retrieve data from a website/app that doesn't offer open APIs

Tags: web-scraping, headless

Let's say, for example, I'm building an application where a user searches for a shirt based on it's UPC code. The application's job is to find that shirt at other various retailers. Retailer A has a API that can be easily used to locate product. However, retailer B doesn't have an API open to developers.

How would a developer handle retailer B?

The ideas that I've come up with were:

- Use a headless browser to load retailer B's website, perform a search, and crawl the webpage. (Which sounds terrible)
- Use a headless browser to load retailer B's website, perform a search, intercept the network traffic. (Better but still not great)

Has anyone encountered this before, or does anyone know of an existing technology or method to approach this issue? I've never understood how you would handle data retrieval without using APIs.

Comment: I've done this with `curl` and it is a pain in the butt because there are an infinite number of retailers without an API, and whenever they modify their websites, you have to rewrite the regexes that you used to parse the page.

Comment: @mankowitz can you share an example of how you were able to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I did in php using curl. It should help get you started.

```
$url = 'https://newjersey.xxxxxx.net/login';
$cookie="cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
preg_match('/meta content="([^"]+)" name="csrf-token"/', $result, $matches);
$token = $matches[1];
$creds['authenticity_token'] = $token;

print "login page with token $token\n";

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://newjersey.xxxxx.net/auth/identity/callback');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($creds));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Once logged in, you can get use a regex to get the data you are looking for.